# why this mysql query doesnt work from php

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, mysqli, phpmyadmin

PHP code from registration procedure:

```
    $query="INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `role`, `time_registration`) 
        VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_SESSION['reg']['email']))."',
                '".hash('SHA512',trim($_POST['password']))."',
                '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_SESSION['rola']))."',
                NOW())";

    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
        error(".....");
    }else{
```

Here is all good. First query is executed and data is stored to table "users". But here comes problem. Next php code generate new mysql query, which is never executed. But when I copy it to PHPmyAdmin, there it works...

```
        $last_id=$con->insert_id;
        $query='';
        foreach($_SESSION['reg'] as $key=>$value){
            if($value!=''){
                $query.=" INSERT INTO user_detail (id_user,id_item,value) VALUES ('".$last_id."', (SELECT id_item FROM profil_items WHERE name='".$key."'), '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value)."');";
            }   
        }

        if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            echo $query; 
        }else{
            header('Location: ...somewhere....');
        }           
    }
```

Mysqli error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO user_detail (id_user,id_item,value) VALUES ('14', (SELECT id_po' at line 1".

I dont understand. If there is an error in syntax, how can by executed without errors in PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: The query in the error mesage doesn't seem to match the query in the "broken" code.

Comment: @ogc-nick I think it's been translated: polozka=item, hodnota=value

Comment: Post the exact text of the query (as output by your `echo` statement).

Comment: `Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with mysqli_multi_query().` -- [reference php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: mysqli_multi_query() fix it. Thank you. 
(polozka=item, hodnota=value -I have translated name for better understanding)

Comment: @showdev has the answer.  Also, I would suggest using the extended syntax (`INSERT INTO Table SET Field1 = 'this', Field2 = 'that'...`), as it's easier to grok and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never any reason to use `mysqli_multi_query()`. Starting a habit of using multi-query opens yourself up to new [types of SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://xkcd.com/327).

You should either execute each INSERT individually, with `mysqli_query()` inside the `foreach` loop.

Or else append multiple rows into one multi-row INSERT statement and execute it after the loop.

---

In this case, no (though you should use bound parameters instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`), but I think once you start using `mysqli_multi_query()` you may use it elsewhere in an unsafe manner. Better to never use it.

You can execute a single INSERT by using multi-row syntax. But I wouldn't worry about the overhead of executing multiple statements, until you are doing it in such high volume that you can measure a significant performance problem. Don't worry about micro-optimizations.

Comment: You are right, but in this case aren't any options to make sql injection. Or they are? The user input is treatment by mysqli_real_escape_string function. Core of the solution was the assumption that a one query is processed faster... Maybe i am wrong.

Comment: "Core of the solution was the assumption" --- never assume, follow the facts.